# ImportError: No module named google.appengine.ext (Cloud Endpoints Frameworks v2)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints

I am trying to use google endpoint v2 
following this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/python/quickstart-frameworks-python)

I have done all steps up until the *To generate the required configuration file:* Step

But when i try the following command

python lib/endpoints/endpointscfg.py get_swagger_spec main.EchoApi --hostname echo-api.endpoints.xxxxxxx.appspot.com

I get the following warning and error

> WARNING: Could not find the fix_sys_path() function in dev_appserver.
>   If you encounter errors, please make sure that your Google App Engine
>   SDK is up-to-date.
>  Traceback (most recent call last): 
>                          
>   File "lib/endpoints/endpointscfg.py", line 59, in 
>           
>   import _endpointscfg_setup  # pylint: disable=unused-import 
>         
>    File "D:\Libraries\Documents\transporter\lib\endpoints_endpointscfg_setup.py",
>   line 107, in 
>          `
>   _SetupPaths()  
>         File "D:\Libraries\Documents\transporter\lib\endpoints_endpointscfg_setup.py",
>   line 103, in _SetupPaths
>        
>   from google.appengine.ext import vendor
>  ImportError: No module named google.appengine.ext

And no OpenAPI configuration file is generated

I have reinstalled everything,updated everything , checked system variables but still getting the error

p.s on windows 7

Comment: google.appengine.ext is part of the App Engine SDK packaged with the Google Cloud SDK. Have you included that location in your python path?

Comment: @HondaGuy This was the answer ,l updated my python paths and it worked :) Thanks

Comment: I do not have enough rep to comment on Tungamirai Mangombe's answer.
For me it was adding: C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine i.e. with the additional: \google\appengine at the end in comparison to his answer. that fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@HondaGuy's Comment was the answer I added app-engine to my python path,

my python environment variable now looks like this

> C:\Python27\Lib;C:\Python27\DLLs;C:\Python27\Lib\lib-tk;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Google\Cloud
>   SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\bundledpython;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine;